# scroll horizontal y espacio en blanco a la dereca versiòn movil

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

estoy completando una pagina web, pero en versión móvil se genera un scroll horizontal a la derecha y se muestra un espacion en blanco o parte del background del footer, no consigo dar con el error. Les agradezco la ayuda.

Estoy comenzando en este mundo del html y css.

esta es la web: http://www.soloviajesdelujo.com/workana/

[image: Scroll no deseado]

Comment: Prueba cambiando la posición del main. `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1):

debes eliminar la línea con la clase "main" en el primer div del body :) Con eso se arregla tu problema.

[image: Borrando eso se me ve así]

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero no me funciono. Al eliminar la clase, el footer queda al incio de la pagina (superpone)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el header de tu aplicacion, los estilos del header deberán quedar como

```
header {
 width: 100vw;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99999;
 padding: 10px 0;}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Revisando actualmente tengo exactamente el header con esos estilos

Comment: Fíjate en el width tu lo tienes como 100%, cámbialo por 100vw

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que normalizar tu proyecto, puedes intentar lo siguiente

box-sizing: border-box
margin: 0
padding: 0
overflow-x: hidden

aplicalo en el selector universal del proyecto que es el "asterisco"